# Javascript Anonymous function within then call

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird

```
exports.index = function(req, res) {
moviedb.indexMovie()
 .then(x => {
    Movie.findAsync()
      .then(responseWithResult(res))
      .catch(handleError(res))
      }
  )
};

function responseWithResult(res, statusCode) {
   statusCode = statusCode || 200;
   console.log("Populating Response");
   return function(entity) {
    if (entity) {
      res.status(statusCode).json(entity);
    }
  };
}
```

The above code works perfectly fine, the returned function in the responsewithresult function, gets populated with the .then response. However, I was experimenting and tried this instead, but it did not work. Please explain why?

```
exports.index = function(req, res) {
  moviedb.indexMovie()
    .then(x => {
       Movie.findAsync()
        .then(x => {responseWithResult(res)}) // <-- this doesn't work
        .catch(handleError(res))
    })
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't work since

```
.then(responseWithResult(res))
```

passes the result of `responseWithResult` (which is a function that eventually returns a value) to the `then` function, whereas

```
x => {responseWithResult(res)}
```

which is logically like

```
function(x) {
  responseWithResult(res);
}
```

and when you put that inside `then(...)`, nothing is returned.

You *could* fix that with

```
then(x => responseWithResult(res))
```

which is like

```
function(x) {
  return responseWithResult(res);
}
```

but really you should refractor your entire function to make better use of promises, and have a cleaner code in the end:

```
exports.index = function(req, res) {
  moviedb.indexMovie()
   .then(() => Movie.findAsync())
   .then(movie => responseWithResult(movie, res))
   .catch(() => handleError(res))
};

function responseWithResult(entity, res, statusCode) {
  statusCode = statusCode || 200;
  console.log("Populating Response");
  res.status(statusCode).json(entity);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Because you're returning undefined, add a `return` before the `responseWithRest` call or remove the `{}`s around it to make it an expression arrow function.

Promises work by return value.

Your first example doesn't sequence operations either. The functions get invoked immediately.

Comment: I got the first part. But can you please elaborate on what you mean by "doesnt sequence operations".

Comment: @Benjamin is correct. Refer the documentation example : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Shorter_functions

Comment: I understand the arrow operation bit now. What is the sequencing thing benjamin spoke about. How can I do it and what are the benefits ?